# XCode project missing files on other Mac

Tags: xcode

I have multiple Xcode Projects in my Dropbox so I can use them on my iMac and MacBook. But when I open the projects on another Mac most of the imported Images, Videos etc... are red (missing). the files are all in the Project Root Folder. What can I do?

Comment: That must be because the file doesn't added as copied. When you add files to your project, you need to check option `Copy items if needed`.

Comment: Also I recommend to use source management system such as `git` instead of using `Dropbox`. Dropbox is not for this kind of purpose.

Comment: @Ryan using source control is a good idea indeed, but be aware that `git` itself only works on a local system, to synchronise `git` repositories over the cloud, OP needs to use a `git` server, such as [github](https://github.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is because when you added the files (images, documents, etc) you did not tick copy if needed option.

That means if you deag/drop items from your desktop to the project, Xcode will reference the documents from your desktop. When opening the project on another computer, the Xcode is not finding your documents in the desktop of the other computer, thus the error.

Solution:

1- Delete all the red marked items (take note of them)

2- move them again to the project and make sure to check copy items if needed checkbox.

3- re upload the project to wherever you need and it will run.

Happy coding!